# ExpressionChangedAfterIsHasBeenCheckedError because of updating my dropdownlist in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

As the title says I'm getting an `ExpressionChangedAfterIsHasBeenCheckedError` and after reading [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4), from what I understand it is a cautionary put in place to prevent inconsistencies. Exactly those words. So at some point I'm probably violating the unidirectional flow (I assume).
What I have:

A dropdown box.

```
<select id="product" [(ngModel)]="model.searchParameters.productId">
 <option *ngFor="let product of products [value]="product.id">{{product.name}}</option>
</select>
```

An input box which triggers checkIban.

```
<div *ngIf="checkIban(productnumber, searchForm)">
   //show validation errors
</div>



checkIban(field: any, form: any): Boolean {
    if(field.dirty)
    {
        if(field.viewModel.length === Productnumber.Iban )
        {
           this.model.searchParameters.productId = Product.Ibannumber;
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to think I understand the concept of the `ExpressionChangedAfterIsHasBeenCheckedError`, unfortunately for me, not well enough to truly apply a proper solution to this problem.

Using `setTimeout` is not an option (I've tried) as it creates an unpredictable state (as was written in the article). 
So can someone give me some pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's usually caused when a bound value changes during change detection. What causes `checkIban` to be called?

Comment: I've updated my answer Günter.

Comment: The `checkIban()` method doesn't even return a value, so this cant work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to add ChangeDetectionStrategy in my solution.

My component now looks like this.

```
@Component{{
selector: 'search',
templateUrl:'./app/search/search.component.html',
changeDetection:ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, 
providers:[SearchService]
})
```

After lots of reading on the subject I came across this solution. That seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Binding to a function in the view is usually a bad idea in Angular, because the function will be called every time change detection runs. When 2 subsequent calls (during a single change detection run) return 2 different results, you get the error message in your question.

Instead use an event to update the result and assign it to a field in your component and then bind to that field instead:

```
<select id="product" [(ngModel)]="model.searchParameters.productId"
    (ngModelChange)="checkIban()">
 <option *ngFor="let product of products [value]="product.id">{{product.name}}</option>
</select>

<div *ngIf="isIbanOk">
   //show validation errors
</div>
```

```
checkIban(field: any, form: any): Boolean {
    ...

    this.isIbanOk = result; // true or false
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm definitely going to try this.